# Table from JSON

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I've a php script which loads basically just one csv via:

```
 echo json_encode(file(csvfile.csv, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));
```

The output is something like this:

```
["foo,bar,baz","foo, foo,bar","bla,bla,blubb"]
```

In my basic html file I load it in this way:

```
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){ 
    $.getJSON("myphpscript.php", function(data) {
      filltable(data);
    })
});

function filltable(jqxhr){
    var table_obj = $('table');
    $.each(jqxhr, function(index, item){
         table_obj.append($('<tr id="'+item.id+'"><td>'+item.data+'</td></tr>'));
    }).insertAfter('.table');
}    
  </script>
```

which fills my `<table id="table"></table>` just with *undefined*.

My goal is it to get a table with 1 column containing:

```
foo,bar,baz
foo, foo,bar
bla,bla,blubb
```

After specify a delimiter my js-function should explode each line and more columns. 
This is my first attempt with javascript and json. Thank you very much

Edit: Fixed function call (Thanks  VisioN) . object.length is now ok, but the table is still undefinied

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might want to use

```
table_obj.append($('<tr id="'+index+'"><td>'+item+'</td></tr>'));
```

instead of

```
table_obj.append($('<tr id="'+item.id+'"><td>'+item.data+'</td></tr>'));
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help when I can.

Answer (score 1):

Your data structure doesn't match the jQuery object parsing schema

You are trying to parse an object that would look like:

```
 [{"id":"foo","data":"foo,bar,baz"}]
```

For one column You just want

```
 table_obj.append($('<tr id="'+item+'</td></tr>'));
```