# Javascript Split() doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, split

I've a php script which loads basically just one csv via:

> echo json_encode(file(csvfile.csv, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES));

The output is something like this:

> ["foo,bar,baz","foo, foo,bar","bla,bla,blubb"]

In my basic html file I load it in this way:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("curlcsvfetcher.php", function(data) { 
    $('#data').empty();
    var columnseperator     =  "|";
    var commentindicator    = "#"; 
    var textqualifier   = '"' 
    filltable2(data,columnseperator,commentindicator,textqualifier); }
 );
```

This works great with the function `filltable()` but not with `filltable2()`:

```
function filltable(data,columnseperator,commentindicator,textqualifier){
    var table_obj = $('table');
    $.each(data, function(index, item){
         table_obj.append($('<tr id="'+item+'"><td>'+item+'</td></tr>'));
    }).insertAfter('.table');
} 
function filltable2(data,columnseperator,commentindicator,textqualifier){
    var table_obj = $('table');
    var trstart = '<tr>';
    var trend = '</tr>';
    $.each(data, function(index, item){
        table_obj.append($('<tr id="'+item+'"><td>'+item+'</td></tr>'));
        var columns = data.split(columnseperator);
        var tddata = '';
        for (var column in columns){
            tddata = tddata +'<td>'+column+'</td>';
            }
        var rowdata = trstart + tddata + trend;
        table_obj.append($(rowdata));

    }).insertAfter('.table');
}
```

The function `filltable()` generate the output with one column and 3 rows. 
But now I want to explode each line in (this case 3) columns.

There must be a problem with my code in function `filltable2()` and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

The output of `filltable2()` is just one line in the table.

Thank you very much!

PS: This problem is related to my [last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12887423/table-from-json) but I think the basic problem is unrelated, so i created a new question

Comment: silly question, you are passing vertical bars as the separator in the CSV, right?

Comment: FYI, both gonzofish and Yogendra found a flaw in the code.. Both issues need to get solved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's because in the split line, you're giving it:

```
data.split(columnseperator);
```

When you mean

```
item.split(columnseperator);
```

or

```
data[index].split(columnseperator);
```

Comment: or
    data[index].split(columnseperator);

Comment: Thank you guys. This was to easy, I think i have to go to bed. 3 am is not a good time for code :-) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

I advice to change your `for` loop:

```
    for (var column in columns){
        tddata = tddata +'<td>'+column+'</td>';
    }
```

as :

```
for (var i= 0; i < columns.length; i++){
  tddata = tddata +'<td>'+columns[i]+'</td>';
}
```

Try this way. If it doesn't work. Please alert `data` before loop and `tddata` after the loop and share.

Comment: Thank you, the for loop is much easy to debug.

Comment: Agreed.  Using `for ... in` with arrays has some rather well known issues ranging from no promise of key order to monkeypatched Array.prototype methods bleeding out.